# How does escaping a literal dot work for sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, double-quotes

The following `sed` command

```
echo '.' | sed "s/\\./foo/"
```

substitutes `.` with `foo`, as expected. However, if we escape the non-alphanumeric `.` in the above command

```
echo '.' | sed "s/\\\./foo/"
```

prints barely `.`, whereas `foo` is expected. `sed` should match the character `.` literally, but it doesn't. I cannot understand what is happening with the dot. I believe that I should simply put a backslash in front of every non-alphanumeric character in bash, if a string is double-quoted. A dot is a non-alphanumeric character so what is wrong about escaping it and why does it produce a different result?

Comment: I'm not surprised that `s/\\\./foo/` doesn't work. I *am* surprised that `s/\\./foo/` *does* work.

Comment: @Beta it's because he wrapped it in double-quotes and thus the shell consumed `\\ ` and passed it to `sed` as a single `\ `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because how backslashes work in bash double quote `"` escaping.

```
echo "\\"
\
echo "\."
\.
echo "s/\\./foo/"
s/\./foo/
echo "s/\\\./foo/"
s/\\./foo/
```

From `man bash`:

```
Within double quotes, the backslash retains its special meaning only when
followed by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \,or <newline>.
```

So in the first case, sed gets `s/\./foo/` and interprets it as "replace a dot with foo". In the second case sed gets `s/\\./foo/` and interprets it as "replace a backslash and one other character with foo.

You better use single quote escaping in this case:

```
echo 's/./foo/'
s/./foo/
echo 's/\./foo/'
s/\./foo/
```

which is probably what you wanted.

Comment: Add the output of echoing with single quotes for comparison and you have my +1

Answer (score 2):

In your second one, the `.` is still a literal dot, but the regular expression only replaces the two-character sequence `\.` (not `.` by itself) with `foo`:

```
$ echo '=\.=' | sed "s/\\\./foo/"
=foo=
```

Comment: Well, that answers my question, but I still feel there is something more subtle about `\.` or \\ or escaping in general that I do not understand.

Comment: I think the subtlety lies in the fact that `bash` will create both `\.` and `\\.` the same, but for different reasons. Since `.` has no special meaning, `\.` is not replaced by anything, so it is passed unchanged to `sed`. ``\`` *does* have special meaning, so `\\.` is first reduced to `\.` by `bash`, which is then passed through to `sed.

Comment: @banan3'14 - the more subtle thing has to do with the shell, and quoting in the shell - not with `sed` in particular. When you use double-quotes instead of single-quotes, the shell still does **some** processing; it evaluates variables and commands, and in particular it still honors the backslash as an escape character. When written in double-quotes like you did, the shell interprets `\\ ` as a single back-slash, and that is what it presents to the `sed` `s` command. This is why you will see that in most cases, people give the `sed` commands in single quotes, not double.

Comment: @mathguy is spot on.  This is the reason